# In javascript, how can I detect when the browser brings up the open/save/cancel prompt when loading a file?

Tags: javascript, browser

In javascript, how can I detect when the browser brings up the open/save/cancel prompt when loading a file?

If possible, is it the same for all browsers?

I'm trying to fix a problem with users clicking a download button, being impatient and clicking it again, and again which is taxing our servers. I tried just hiding the button while the file is processed, but the icon will come back before the open/save/cancel prompt shows up.

The code goes something like this: 
... 
users clicks button, 
button hides, 
external process gets the file, 
button appears ...

Comment: It's not possible. What do you want to do? Maybe there are workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

How the browser deals with a requested resource - open it, start an external application, offer a "save" dialog - is outside of what you can control using JavaScript.

Comment: All I want to do is detect when it comes up. Is that not even possible?

Comment: @chemdt nope, definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! No way, that's it!